# Access Denied when trying to debug on Windows Phone 8.1 device

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, remote-debugging

I've been working on a Windows Phone 8.1 application using mostly the emulator and a Nokia Lumia 520.

Up until yesterday, debugging on the device was working fine. However, because I wanted to back out of a pending update to Windows 10 on the device **I ran the Windows Phone Recovery tool** (I never actually updated to Windows 10).

Now that I've reinstalled WP8.1 on the device, I'm having trouble debugging.

This is the error message I'm getting:

[image: Access Denied error message]

(the pixelated part points to the bin\Debug path of the project). Note that even though it says "Windows Store app", this is actually a Windows Phone app.

Deploying to the device works fine. I've tried debugging on two different machines now, with the same result. I've discovered that if I explicitly set the **CPU type** in Visual Studio to **ARM**, then debugging actually works, although it seems to be a lot slower than before.

Does anyone know why I'm suddenly getting this weird error message and why I suddenly need to compile specifically for ARM CPUs to debug on my phone?